# How can I get Argumants that start with specific parameter in URL Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django App. I want if URL send to Django include `http://127.0.0.1:8000/flower/blue/mix/2/1` get value `/blue/mix/2/1`.
I try this pattern but not work:

urls.py:

```
 path('flower/<str:queryparams>',views.flower,name='flower'),
 re_path(r'^flower/(?:page-(?P<page_number>\d+)/)?$',views.flower,name='flower2'),
```

views.py:

```
def flower(self,request,response):
    path = request.get_full_path()# not work
    print(path)# not work
    print(self.kwargs['parameter']) # not work
    print(request.get['str'])  # not work
    print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    return response
```

Comment: why not try something like this =>   `re_path(r'^flower/(?P<color>\w+)/(?P<type_name>\w+)/(?P<sub1>\d+)/(?P<sub2>\d+)$', .......)`

Comment: ok. How can i get this values in views.py?

Comment: See my  answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[views arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments) is what you need. You can define variables in you `urls.py` like this:

```
re_path(r'^flower/(?P<color>\w+)/(?P<type_name>\w+)/(?P<sub1>\d+)/(?P<sub2>\d+)$',views.flower,name='flower2')
```

in your `views.py` you can use them as views arguments like this (if you are not useing [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/)):

```
def flower(request, color, type_name, sub1, sub2):
    print(color, type_name, sub1)
    # do whatever you want with them
```

Comment: I don't write `r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+` but not work too.

Comment: No,It haven't any error. just write in terminal: `Not Found: /blue/mix/2/1   and [02/May/2020 19:13:35] "GET  /blue/mix/2/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 4505 `

Comment: @JohnKennedy You should go to this address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/flower/blue/mix/2/1` not `/blue/mix/2/1`

Answer (score 0):

this code work too:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
           path('flower/<str:A>/<str:B>/<int:C>/<int:D>',views.flower,name='flower') 
            ]
```

views.py:

```
def flower(request,A,B,C,D):
    print(A)
    print(B)
    print(C)
    print(D)
```